# Calculate the total lengths of the segments intersect each of some polygons

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I have a raster (ras variable in my code below) and some shapefiles of roads (temp variable in my code below is one shapefile). I want to get the road lengths within each cell of the raster. There can be several features in one shapefile of roads. I used the code in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280760/intersecting-lines-and-polygons-and-calculating-line-length-in-r) to get the lengths calcualted. My question is about assigning the road lengths back to the raster. I am not quite sure if the lengths from the out variable is matching the raster cells in correct sequence (the second to the last line in my code below). Can anyone help me with identifying if I am assigning values correctly? Thank you!!

```
temp<-readOGR(dsn=paste(dir2,"step0",sep=""),layer=n1[i])   
temp<-spTransform(temp,proj4string(ras)) #took long time
e1<-extent(temp)
ras_crop<-crop(ras,e1) #crop gedi to the extent of the vector
poly <- rasterToPolygons(ras_crop)
temp<-st_as_sf(temp)
poly<-st_as_sf(poly)
inte<-st_intersection(temp,poly)
inte$len<-st_length(inte) #length of each line segment
poly$id<-1:nrow(poly) 
join<-st_join(poly,inte)
out<-group_by(join,id) %>% summarize(length=sum(len))
mutate(out,length=ifelse(is.na(length),0,length))
ras_crop[]<-out$length #this is the raster of road distance
writeRaster(ras_crop,filename=paste(dir2,"step1/",n1[i],sep=""),format="GTiff",overwrite=T)
```